# InvalidPayloadException during camel marshalling

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to marshall java object from came queue, but I am getting InvalidPayloadException even after mentioning the object factory class properly. Please find my code below:

```
 //JaxB Config
 JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.ObjectFactory.class);

 // POGO configuration in Jaxb component for responsexml insertion
            JaxbDataFormat jaxbMarshalXmlInsertion = new JaxbDataFormat(jc);
            jaxbMarshalXmlInsertion .setContextPath(MyPojo.class.getName());
            jaxbMarshalXmlInsertion .setPartClass(MyPojo.class.getName());



//My Route
from("vm:ResponseQueue").
 .log("In response XML body before Marshall-------------->${body}")
    .marshal(jaxbMarshalXmlInsertion )
    .log("In response XML body After Marshall-------------->${body}")
 to(vm:XmlQueue);


//Log(The log before the marshal code is printed correctly in fuse.log)
In response XML body before Marshall-------------->com.MyPojo@2cf745ca


//Excerption I got
InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement but has value: com.MyPojo@2cf745ca of type: com.MyPojoon: Message[ID-B526DCOK-51386-1514355409371-5-121]. Exchange[ID-B526DCOK-51386-1514355409371-5-122]
```

Can anyone please help me identify what I missed and help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from("vm:ResponseQueue").
 .streamCaching()
 .log("In response XML body before Marshall-------------->${body}")
    .marshal(jaxbMarshalXmlInsertion )
    .log("In response XML body After Marshall-------------->${body}")
 to(vm:XmlQueue);
```

see more details http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not working. Got the same exception